# Mapping onto a cylinder with threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is there a way to map an image onto the side of a cylinder with threejs? Would I have to map individual portions of the image onto each face on the side of the cylinder, or is there a faster way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you're looking for a `map` parameter of a material. Have a look at [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Materials/MeshBasicMaterial)

Answer (score 0):

For all texture allocation and mapping you probably want to know about [UV Mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping) which you typically do before importing into Threejs. All 3D modeling programs have that functionality, [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) is the most popular and arguably the best among the free ones.